# Как правильно построить плавно возрастающую функцию в MATLAB?

Tags: циклы, график, matlab

Дана задача:  построить плавно возрастающую функцию. Пытался решить таким образом:

```
clear,clc
X=-5:1:10
y1=[]
y2=[]
K=0:0.1:1.3
for x=X
    if x<0
       y1=[y1 0]
     end
end
for k=K
    if k<=1
       y2=[y2 x*k]
    end
end
Y=[y1 y2]
plot(X,Y)
```

Но на графике идет резкое искривление кривой, т.е. x=y. Я же рассчитывал на значения по типу x=1, y=1 * 0.1, x=2,y=2 * 0.2 и т.д. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: о какой ошибке речь? [ask]

Comment: график функции во втором цикле начинает резко расти вверх, т.е. значению y2 присваивается значение х, а необходимо присвоить значение k*x, где k плавно растет от 0 до 1.3 с шагом 0,1

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Всё значительно проще:

```
x=-5:10;
y=0.1*x.*(x>=0);
plot(x,y)
```

И ставьте точку с запятой в конце строки, чтобы на дисплей не выводились все результаты, особенно большие массивы чисел.

Answer (score 0):

После выполнения первого цикла в переменной `x` остаётся последнее значение `X`, т.е. `10`. Соответственно в `y2` во втором цикле попадают значения `10 * 0`, `10 * 0.1` и т.д., т.е. `0, 1, 2, ...` Если вы хотите получить в `y2` значения `10.1`, `20.2` и т.д., то, наверное, и умножать `k` нужно не на `10`, а на `101`:

```
for k=K
    if k<=1
       y2=[y2 101*k]
    end
end
```

Вернее, тут первый элемент будет `0`, если он вам не нужен, то сделайте `y2=[y2 101*(k+1)]`

Comment: Мне необходимо получить такую модель, чтобы x продолжала принимать значения от 0 и до 10, а у принимал k*x, где k идет с шагом в 0,1